# Importing into Gender Field in SQL/SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

How would you handle importing only male (m) or female (f) data into a gender field, so that it won't get populated with any potential extraneous source data, in SQL or SSIS?

Comment: I'd create a check constraint on the field. That will stop the table ever containing data of that type. If your SSIS or anything tries to insert something else, it will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Gender varchar(1),
CONSTRAINT chk_Gender CHECK (Gender ='m' or Gender='f')
)

Insert into Persons values(1,'smith', 'jane', 'f');
insert into Persons values(2,'smith', 'john', SUBSTRING('male', 1, 1));
/* this will fail
INSERT INTO Persons values (3,'foo', 'bar', 'u');
*/
select * FROM Persons;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/550)

Comment: Thanks, scottJustin5000.

Answer (score 1):

It's trival to add a check constraint, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
  GENDER CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT Constraint_Gender CHECK (GENDER IN ('A','B','C'))
)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('D')

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 9
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "Constraint_Gender".
```

However, you should really cater for non-binary genders in a similar manner to facebook etc https://www.facebook.com/facebookdiversity/posts/774221582674346 (hence A, B, C in my example above)